# Can't find ckpasswd for inn2

Tags: linux, centos6.2

I'm attempting to set up an intranet news server, inn2, and I'm stuck at setting up user authentication.

My readers.conf file looks like this:

```
auth all {
    auth: "ckpasswd -d <pathdb in inn.conf>/newsusers"
    auth: "ckpasswd -s"
}

access full {
    users: *
    newsgroups: *
}
```

I created a password database using a Perl script named dbmpasswd that I grabbed from somewhere. This script created two files, `newsusers.pag` and `newsusers.dir`.

In the `auth all` block above, I'm referencing a program called `ckpasswd` but I can't find this program on my system (CentOS 6.2) anywhere. `yum whatprovides` returns nothing and it's not in my path. Google doesn't turn up much either.

Where can I find `ckpasswd` and more important, I suppose--is this the right way to set up authentication for inn2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On my Ubuntu and Centos 5 systems, `ckpasswd` is part of `inn2` and found as `/usr/lib/news/bin/auth/passwd/ckpasswd`. I'd be surprised if it's not there on Centos 6.

Comment: It was actually located at /usr/libexec/news/auth/passwd/ckpasswd but your answer pointed me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

Older version of yum would erroneously match against files, now you must explicitly specify the behavior with something like */ckpasswd:

```
$ yum provides */ckpasswd
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror 
Reducing CentOS-5 Testing to included packages only
Finished
inn-2.4.3-9.el5.i386 : The InterNetNews (INN) system, an Usenet news server.
Repo        : base
Matched from:
Filename    : /usr/lib/news/bin/auth/passwd/ckpasswd
```

So now that you know where it is ensure that its in your $PATH or specify the full path in your config.